# What is the wattage of the speakers in a 2011 MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, speakers

I have recently purchased a MacBook Air and the speakers sound tiny. Does anyone know how many watts the speakers in the 2011 Macbook Airs have?

Comment: Would that be "tinny", not "tiny"?

Comment: The number of watts is irrelevant here.  The size of the speaker is the limiting factor and given the size of the MacBook Air, it shouldn't be a surprise you're not getting "big" sound.

Comment: My 2011 air is quite loud. Lounder than my all previous notebooks really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is - not many.

The [iFixit teardown](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook-Air-11-Inch-Model-A1370-Teardown/3745/2) of an earlier model (mid-2010) suggests 1-2 watts. The [teardown of the 2011 model](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook-Air-13-Inch-Mid-2011-Teardown/6130/2) says nothing has changed since then.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree. I think finding the real value may be quite challenging. 1.5-3 watts seems like a good ballpark figure. And really, would it matter if it was a couple watts more?